# Can I stream a .mp3-link with the AV Foundation Framework on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I'm making an app for someone who has his own radio. 
It's only a stream URL (ex. http://stream.domain.com/highquality.mp3)
I've made yet the code with the AV Foundation Framework to let it work with a simple .mp3-file.

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)play {
if(clicked == 0) {
    clicked = 1;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    [audioPlayer play];
    [start setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    [audioPlayer stop];
    clicked = 0;
    [start setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

What should I edit?

Edit: The code above really works. I need to let it work with a button to play and stop it. I don't want to have a hole media player on my device. Simply and beautiful..

**Edit 2: Some people don't find what I need: I need the edits to let it work with the .mp3 stream (as example a stream above).**

Comment: is it working or not? I implemneted a mp3 stream in of my last apps with Media Player Framework which also worked very nice.

Comment: Yes it's working.. I added an file: test.mp3 in my app and everything works..

Comment: So if it works what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to let it work with a stream as the example in my question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass a NSURL to your player object to make it play the stream from there

```
-(IBAction)play {
if(clicked == 0) {
    clicked = 1;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.linktoyourstream.com"];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    [audioPlayer play];
    [start setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried it but doesn't work with my stream.. Is there a requirement for a stream? It's high quality.. (Update: also low quality doesn't work..)

Comment: how did you test it? try to upload the mp3 file to a webserver and call the URL to that file to make sure it is not the stream

Comment: I tested it with the simulator. This evening I can test it with a device... How can I do that?

Comment: You need a developer account in order to test applications on your device.

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is not supposed to be used for streaming data, the initWithContentsOfURL parameter only takes the url of a locally stored file, not a remote one. Another solution would be for you to download the file, then pass the url to the file to AVAudioPlayer